# Ambiguous(?) meaning

Tags: terms-of-service

*Disputes handled by TeamX can only address the hours, not the quality.*

What does it mean:

1. TeamX can only address hours in handling the dispute, not the quality
   or
2. dispute can only address hours not the quality

[image]

I find answers to this question I asked elsewhere very interesting and divergent, but asking here for the second opinion as I also got an answer from a court interpreter which was quite surprising in the interpretation of the sentence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Courts always answer these questions with far more context than you have provided. A bare sentence in the abstract is insufficient. One would need to know what kind of document the sentence appeared in, what kind of business TeamX is, and more, in order to answer it meaningfully.

Comment: Courts also want to see the actual text, not the paraphrase by an interested party.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence has a rather easy-to-spot subject (construction): `Disputes [handled by TeamX]`. This is the verb construction is `can [only] address` and it has two objects: `only [address] the hours` as well as `not the quality`. The `only` clearly belongs to the first object, but makes no grammatical sense with the second. The sentence would be arguably less ambiguous if there was a `but` after the comma for `[but] not the quality`.

As such, the sentence is easy: TeamX can only handle (address) disputes regarding the *length* of work (hours). **But** TeamX can not handle disputes about the quality of work.

Comment: "only" modifies "address," not "hours."  They can address the hours; they cannot address the quality.  In fact, it modifies the whole phrase "address the hours"; you could just as well say "they can only address the hours and not slice the apple."  It's just that "address" is implicit in the last phrase.  If you want "only" to modify "hours," you should say "they can address only the hours and not the quality."

Comment: @phoog the only is part of the "the hours" part, but not of the "the quality" part, where it makes no sense, that's why I put it over to the other part. "Can only address not the quality" is not grammatical - for that part, the sentence is "XY can [not] address [...] the quality" ;  a different way would be to inject the implicit *but* before "not the quality", to achieve grammaticality.

Comment: "But" is not necessary to achieve grammaticality.  My point is that "only" can refer to verbs, as it does here.  For example, one can say, "they can only run, not walk."  This sentence is "they can only address the hours, not [address] the quality," where the second "address" is in square brackets because it is implied.  This sentence is perfectly grammatical whether one includes the second "address" or not.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the conclusions of the other answers that are based on dictionaries and grammar, but I answer to add that these interpretations do not necessarily match the legal interpretation.

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

See *Sattva Capital Corp. v. Creston Moly Corp.*, [2014 SCC 53](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/14302/index.do) (citations omitted):

> [48] ... the interpretation of contracts has evolved towards a practical, common-sense approach not dominated by technical rules of construction. The overriding concern is to determine “the intent of the parties and the scope of their understanding”. To do so, a decision-maker must read the contract as a whole, giving the words used their ordinary and grammatical meaning, consistent with the surrounding circumstances known to the parties at the time of formation of the contract. Consideration of the surrounding circumstances recognizes that ascertaining contractual intention can be difficult when looking at words on their own, because words alone do not have an immutable or absolute meaning:
>
> > No contracts are made in a vacuum: there is always a setting in which they have to be placed. . . . In a commercial contract it is certainly right that the court should know the commercial purpose of the contract and this in turn presupposes knowledge of the genesis of the transaction, the background, the context, the market in which the parties are operating.
>
> [48] The meaning of words is often derived from a number of contextual factors, including the purpose of the agreement and the nature of the relationship created by the agreement. As stated by Lord Hoffmann:
>
> > **The meaning which a document (or any other utterance) would convey to a reasonable [person] is not the same thing as the meaning of its words.** The meaning of words is a matter of dictionaries and grammars; the meaning of the document is what the parties using those words against the relevant background would reasonably have been understood to mean. [p. 115]

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean:
>
> 1. TeamX can only address hours in handling the dispute, not the
>    quality or
> 2. dispute can only address hours not the quality

The statement "*Disputes handled by TeamX can only address the hours, not the quality*" is poorly written. Regardless, only option 1 makes sense.

Rather than *addressing* something, disputes *are* about something. Only entities address a dispute, whether it is by discussing it, litigating it, ruling on it, or otherwise processing it (for purposes of billing, time management, and so forth). Accordingly, although the statement makes no sense, notions premised on "what a dispute can address" are to be ruled out.

An acceptable wording of option 2 is "*only disputes regarding hours, not quality, may be addressed by TeamX*", thereby paraphrasing option 1.

Specifying what "surprising" interpretation you got from the court interpreter might have prompted us to ponder points or subtleties that otherwise are going unnoticed.

Comment: not sure about youre comment on 'addressing' usage.. it is very common to say https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chapter+addresses%22

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22agreement+addresses%22
etc.

Comment: @johndoe The expression "*this chapter addresses xyz*" ultimately means that the author(s) discussed xyz in that chapter. Although also intelligible, the expression "*the dispute addresses xyz*" seems both odd from the standpoint of common usage and pointless in the context of the clause at issue. Anything could be the cause of a dispute and no clause can prevent that from happening, but a clause certainly can restrict the kinds of disputes that TeamX is allowed to handle.

Comment: it can also mean initiator of dispute addressed hours while TeamX handled the dispute ...

Comment: @johndoe "*it can also mean initiator of dispute addressed hours while TeamX handled the dispute*". That is quite a stretch. There is no context or information to support that interpretation. The statement at issue makes no distinction between initiator and others. Nor does the statement outline what is permissible *during* TeamX's handling of a dispute it is allowed to handle.

Comment: Not a stretch. previously in the clause it is mention that a client initiates a dispute. It certainly is not initiated by the TeamX who is only handling the dispute between a client and a freelancer. but guess it is not clear from a single sentence above..

Comment: @johndoe "*previously in the clause it is mention that a client initiates a dispute.*" You did not mention it in your description, and therefore we cannot be expected to know that. To avoid speculation we mostly limit ourselves to the information an OP provides. "*but guess it is not clear from a single sentence above.*" Not clear at all. For instance, the information you provided in the description does not even mention that the clause is between a client and a freelancer, although that in particular is not very relevant to the actual question.

Comment: Of course, "dispute" doesn't only refer to a disagreement between parties.  "Disputes" can also refer to a dispute resolution team's units of work -- cases, if you will, analogous to court cases.  So it's not very precise, and it is ambiguous, as you note, but depending on the context the ambiguity may not be significant.